# On Desktop: How to Detect if Network is Using Mobile Data

Tags: android, bash, networking, mobile, tethering

Our mobile apps have settings to limit their data usage when we're connected to mobile data network as opposed to when we're connected over Wi-Fi. This appears to be true even when we are tethering. A mobile client, though connected via tethered Wi-Fi, does detect that it's using mobile data and limits data usage.

**Here's the problem:** a laptop client connected to tethered Wi-Fi is agnostic to data usage limits. I'm my case this includes scripts that automatically updates the system and syncs my files.

**Question:** Is there a way for a laptop/desktop system (I'm on Linux, using `bash` scripts) to detect that we're using mobile data?

Comment: Yes. The internet ip will be different from that from the usual router.

Comment: And probably the WLAN ip will already be different.

Answer (score 1):

**If you know at least one of the provider** (mobile or not mobile), you should be able to recognize which is the case, based on the hostname. Here is an example in my case:

```
# Find your own Internet IP, using some free API
$ curl 'https://api.ipify.org'
AAA.BBB.CCC.DDD

# Find the "hostname" of this IP
$ nslookup AAA.BBB.CCC.DDD

DDD.CCC.BBB.AAA.in-addr.arpa \
    name = ip-AAA-BBB-CCC-DDD.web.vodafone.de.

Authoritative answers can be found from:
# It's a "mobile" IP (recognizable in this case bc of the ".web." part)

# Find your own Internet IP, using some free API
$ curl 'https://api.ipify.org'
WWW.XXX.YYY.ZZZ

# Find the "hostname" of this IP
$ nslookup WWW.XXX.YYY.ZZZ

ZZZ.YYY.XXX.WWW.in-addr.arpa \
    name = dslb-WWW-XXX-YYY-ZZZ.NNN.MMM.pools.vodafone-ip.de.

Authoritative answers can be found from:
# It's a "landline" IP (recognizable in this case bc of the "dslb-" part)
```

Comment: Oh thanks. I've practically forgotten about this question from six years ago. Thanks for your answer on a specific use case. I'll upvote it. I'll also post the workaround I've been using that I also forgot to post here. Thanks for bumping this  question.

Comment: @Majal I asked about the same thing *for Windows* (I have a bad DSL), and jut got downvoted with no answer. So I came up with this "special case" which is OS-independent. With a bit of code I now have a red/green DSL Status light. No more running out of mobile "volume" before the end of the month. :)

Answer (score 1):

This command will show whether you are in a metered connection or not:

```
$ nmcli -t -f GENERAL.METERED device show ${network_interface}
```

All your network interfaces can be shown with this command:

```
$ ip link
```

You can get your currently connected WiFi network interface with this command:

```
$ nmcli device status | grep -w wifi | grep -w connected | cut -d ' ' -f1
```

In Network Manager, there is a checkbox to **manually set** whether your connection is metered or not. Otherwise, Network Manager will try to **guess** it.

[image: Metered connection]

If you are using scripts to figure out whether the current WiFi connection is set to metered or not, you could use this template:

```
[ "$(nmcli -t -f GENERAL.METERED device show \
  $(nmcli device status | grep -w wifi | grep -w connected | cut -d ' ' -f1) | \
  cut -d ' ' -f1)" = "GENERAL.METERED:yes" ] && {
    # do whatever if metered
  } || {
    # do whatever if not metered
  }
```